# Using sphinxsearch with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, sphinx

I'm trying to get SphinxSearch to work with Laravel. I've installed it according to instructions given [here](https://github.com/scalia/sphinxsearch). However, I can't get the querying to work, and I can't find any working examples available online either.

This is what I am trying - (Note : **the given email exists in the table**)

```
$results = SphinxSearch::search('user12_mail@gmail.com','testindex')->get();

dd($results);
```

I also tried it with the query itself instead of a 'search term' -

```
$results = SphinxSearch::search('select * from user_directory where Email like user12_mail@gmail.com','testindex')->get();

dd($results);
```

This is my config file-

```
return array (
    'host'    => '127.0.0.1',
    'port'    => 9312,
    'indexes' => array (
        'testindex' => array ( 'table' => 'user_directory', 'column' => 'Email' ),
    )
);
```

Upon running my server and loading the page, `$results` contains only `boolean False`. Am I wrong in the way I am executing my search?

Note : I am running my test server using Artisan's `serve`, which runs on port 8000, does that matter here?

Edit : Been working on this for a very long time now with no avail. I've followed the code in the `sphinxsearch.php` file line by line, still unable to determine why the query returns null! Any help is immensely appreciated

E̶d̶i̶t̶ ̶2̶ ̶:̶ ̶I̶s̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶e̶p̶e̶n̶d̶e̶n̶c̶y̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶`̶c̶o̶m̶p̶o̶s̶e̶r̶.̶j̶s̶o̶n̶`̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶r̶u̶n̶n̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶`̶u̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶`̶ ̶e̶n̶o̶u̶g̶h̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶t̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶S̶p̶h̶i̶n̶x̶?̶ ̶O̶r̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶I̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶*̶*̶m̶a̶n̶u̶a̶l̶l̶y̶*̶*̶ ̶d̶o̶w̶n̶l̶o̶a̶d̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶[̶h̶e̶r̶e̶]̶[̶2̶]̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶t̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶w̶e̶l̶l̶?̶

Edit 3 : Installed the `gigablah/sphinxphp` dependency (My mistake, did not know about this as I didn't pay attention to composer's error message before). Still does not work unfortunately!

Edit 4 : Sphinx for windows installed and fully configured and indexed... Still not working.

Comment: I admit I dont know fur sure, but pretty sure composer wont install sphinx server. It will just download the sphinxsearch client package for use in php. Will still need to install the sphinx server daemon itself, http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#installation

Comment: You say installed, but have to started the searchd service? Try using test.php from the api directory in the sphinx download. That might give you more meaningful messages.

Comment: Sphinx by itself works when I query it from the prompt

Comment: which prompt? I hope you don't mean 'search' command line tool

Comment: That is exactly what I mean, Sphinx by itself works fine. I have now also managed to get this to work via the default Sphinx API, just unable to use the two packages listed above..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you get when you try this?

```
    $results = SphinxSearch::search('term','index')->get();

dd($results);
```

Comment: WOW this made me realize I had a typo in my index! Interchanging I and l is hard to see! Thank you so much this was driving me near insane!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at
https://github.com/scalia/sphinxsearch/blob/master/src/Scalia/SphinxSearch/SphinxSearch.php

notice the get() function, never actully checks the error returned from the sphinxAPI.

getLastError should be used in case of failures, to find out what happened.

There is a getErrorMessage function so try calling that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check it out! But is my syntax correct? :)